# Testing rails 'select' with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

We are doing the following in our Rails app:

```
sums = OrderItem.where(id: oiids).select("sum(quantity_shipped) as quantity_shipped_sum, sum(price) as price_sum, sum(discount) as discount_sum, tenant_id").first
```

after this `select` we can do `sums.quantity_shipped_sum` on the returned `Association`.

How to write a test with this in Rspec? Everything I do tells me that `OrderItem does not implement quantity_shipped_sum` or similar errors.
To be clear, `quantity_shipped_sum` is NOT a method/attribute on `OrderItem`, it is just created by this select.

I have tried

```
allow(OrderItem).to receive(:quantity_shipped_sum).and_return(2)
```

and

```
allow(OrderItem).to receive(:first).and_return(instance_double(OrderItem, quantity_shipped_sum: 2, price_sum: 10.0, discount_sum: 1.0, tenant_id: 1))
```

For a bit more context, here is some more of the `spec` file:

```
allow(OrderItem).to receive(:where).and_return(OrderItem)
allow(OrderItem).to receive(:select).and_return(OrderItem)
allow(OrderItem).to receive(:distinct).and_return(OrderItem)
allow(OrderItem).to receive(:pluck).and_return([order_item1.id, order_item2.id])
allow(OrderItem).to receive(:first).and_return(instance_double(OrderItem, quantity_shipped_sum: 2, price_sum: 10.0, discount_sum: 1.0, tenant_id: 1))
```

I think I know why these are failing - because they are on the Class whereas the `where` returns a Collection/Association.

Comment: Hey Phil. You're correct about why you're getting `OrderItem does not implement quantity_shipped_sum`. But, I need to see your test code to understand a bit more context. Can you add it to your question?

Comment: What more can I add? I've added a bit more, but I am not sure how much I can put up because it is deep in biz logic stuff.

Comment: That helped. Thanks! Hope the answer gives you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues. Let's start here:

Your code is doing this:

```
OrderItem.where(...).select(...).first
```

This code executes a SQL `SELECT` statement against the `order_items` table, returns an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation` containing instances of `OrderItem`, and then grabs the first `OrderItem` instance in the `Relation`.

Your test stubs are doing this:

```
allow(OrderItem).to receive(:where).and_return(OrderItem)
```

This correctly stubs the `where` method. But, returns the OrderItem class, not an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`. So, now, when your code executes, `select` will be called against an `OrderItem` class. This appears to work because `OrderItem` inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` which does have a `select` method. But, technically, it's not correct.

The same goes for all of the `allow(OrderItem)` statements.

The real problem is here:

```
allow(OrderItem)
  .to receive(:first)
  .and_return(
    instance_double(
      OrderItem, 
      quantity_shipped_sum: 2, 
      price_sum: 10.0, 
      discount_sum: 1.0, 
      tenant_id: 1
    )
  )
```

In your code, `first` is called on an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`. It is not called on the `OrderItem` class as specified by the `allow` statement. RSpec does not throw an error on that because `OrderItem` inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` which happens to contain a `first` method (as described above). However, `OrderItem` does not have methods called `quantity_shipped_sum`, `price_sum`, or `discount_sum`. And RSpec's `instance_double` method only allows you to stub methods that actually appear in the class definition.

I think you actually want something like this:

```
let(:order_item_with_sums) do
  instance_double(
    "order item", 
    quantity_shipped_sum: 2, 
    price_sum: 10.0, 
    discount_sum: 1.0, 
    tenant_id: 1
  )
end 

it "makes the correct calls" do
  expect(OrderItem)
    .to receive_message_chain(:where, :select, :first)

  result = # call the method that does the work here...
end
```

Note that the `instance_double` is not using the `OrderItem` class. That would turn on the feature of RSpec that validates that the stubbed methods exist on the class. By using the string `"order item"`, you disable that feature.

It's also important to note that this syntax won't allow you to verify any of the parameters that are passed into `where` and `select`. You'd need different tests for that.

Finally, in order to head off the inevitable comments that you should not use `receive_message_chain`, I will say that the general guidance is that [`receive_message_chain`](https://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-mocks/RSpec%2FMocks%2FExampleMethods:receive_message_chain) is considered a smell since it allows you to fairly easily violate the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). But, this is ActiveRecord. And, ActiveRecord uses a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) to chain methods together. Those method chains are not considered a violation of the Law of Demeter. They are a feature of the framework.

Comment: Wow that's great! I am going to give this a go today. Are you saying that the original code is not quite right? This is the way I have always done sums at a database level from inside of Rails. Happy to learn if there is a better way (if you want to update your answer). Otherwise...thanks again! An education! I am new to Rspec.

Comment: I am getting an error: `expected OrderItem to respond to has_received_message_chain?`

Comment: Oops. Didn't quite have the syntax correct. Updated answer.

Comment: The sum calculation in SQL is fine. But, the stubs you're setting up aren't doing what you think they are.